# retrieve transaction customer's transaction history to put on website

Tags: braintree

I am currently developing an application similar to that of Uber.  I wonder if there is somewhere that I can learn about how to show users' transaction history the way that Uber does on their website.  How can we retrieve that information from Braintree?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should have an attempt to code it for people to help you with here, people wont provide you with code/tutorials.

Comment: I work at Braintree. Feel free to [email our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) for questions like this. Stack Overflow is for specific, technical questions, usually about a specific piece of code that isn't working.